# How to remove a UIView at the end of an animation?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, animation, uiview

I want this label to be removed once the animation is done. And I'd like to not see it again while animating in the following code inside my touchesEnded function.  I don't see a way to check if lbl.isAnimating  already to ignore it in the for loop ( without creating my own list of UILabels ), but I would have thought my completion code here would work.  But after the animation is over I still fall into the if point is inside block if I click on the invisible label.

```
    for( lbl in mLabelOutletCollection ) {

      if (CGRectContainsPoint([lbl frame], [touch locationInView:self.view]))
      {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0
                options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction)
                         animations:^{
                             lbl.alpha = 0.0;
                             lbl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.5, 1.5); 
                         }

                         completion:^(BOOL  completed){
                             [lbl removeFromSuperview];
                             lbl.hidden=YES;
                         }
         ];
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Override

```
- (void)finishAnimation:(NSString *)animationId finished:(BOOL)finished context:(void *)context {
```

And put the:

```
[lbl removeFromSuperview];
lbl.hidden=YES;
```

there.
Also, not sure but I do not believe you need the second line lbl.hidden; since you are already removing it from the superview.

Comment: Thats the old way no? My complete function is called, but I guess the label still responds since it still exists in the IBOutletCollection...

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a bool and doing this after the loop. Even though the lbl was removed, it still existed in the OutletCollection and remembered where it was. I had tried this before, but was doing it inside the loop which causes an exception.

```
    if ( found ) [mLabelOutletCollection removeObject:lbl];
```